# Python regex that will require at least 6 characters to return true

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

one of the criteria is to accept strings that are at least 6 characters
and this is my code:

```
regex = ("^(?=.*[a-z]\S)(?=.*[A-Z]\S)(?=.*[0-9]\S)")
```

i tried putting a `{6,}`
at the end of my code but it still accepts strings below 6 characters...

all of the requirements is:

- contains a lowercase letter (at least one)
- contains an uppercase letter (at least one)
- contains a digit (at least one)
- only contains alphanumeric characters (note that '_' is not alphanumeric)

**TEST CASES**

```
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'fjd3IR9')), True)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'ghdfj32')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'DSJKHD23')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'dsF43')), False) 
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, '4fdg5Fj3')), True)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'DHSJdhjsU')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'fjd3IR9.;')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'fjd3  IR9')), False) 
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'djI38D55')), True)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'a2.d412')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'JHD5FJ53')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, '!fdjn345')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'jfkdfj3j')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, '123')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'abc')), False)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, '123abcABC')), True)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'ABC123abc')), True)
test.assert_equals(bool(search(regex, 'Password123')), True)
```

***all credits to codewars and to its author...***

Comment: could you please add some examples for valid and non-valid strings?

Comment: Try `regex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$"`

Comment: hello sir wiktor your answer was correct but i dont want the string to accept any symbols and white spaces is it possible?

Comment: @TootsyRoll: Use `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$`

Comment: mygod sir your answer was correct all the way holy moly.. sheesh thank you very much ill read your code and understand it further thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
regex = (r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]{6,}$")
```

If you use re module, it will find you any string with 6 or more chars if you test it.
Code here for ex:

```
import re

txt = "string"
print(re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]{6,}$", txt))
```

If the strings has less than 6 chars, it will not be found.

Comment: hello my fellow coders, sorry i was unable to provide all of the criteria, and now i edited my post for you to understand the problem more, i added all of the criteria to satisfy...